# Unit test, how to test? wanted but not invoked on Mockito.verify

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have **GatewayServer.class** with constructor and method:

```
public class GatewayServer {

    private ResourceConfig resourceConfig = null;

    public GatewayServer(...) {
    
            ...
    
            resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();

            ...
    }

    public void registerController(Class<?> controller) {
            resourceConfig.register(controller);
    }
```

And I have **GatewayServerTest.class** where I want to test if `register()` method was called on resourceConfig but I don't know how to add mock of `new ResourceConfig()`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GatewayServerTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    GatewayServer gatewayServer;
    
    @Mock
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(...);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void registerControllerTest() {
        
        gatewayServer.registerController(Endpoint.class);
        
        Mockito.verify(resourceConfig, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).register(Mockito.any());
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do it with Mockito, but you can use PowerMock which can mock the constructor itself.

Another solution is to initialize `Resource config` not in the constructor but in place (if you don't have any post-initialization):

```
private ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
```

In this case, mocking with Mockito is possible (like you did in your test class).

Comment: With last solution I won't be able to verify if the method was called because it's not a mock.

Comment: You shouldn't initialize `GatewayServer` in test either (with `new`). It will be instantiated via `@injectMocks` annotation, and all mock will be injected into it automatically.

Comment: So, if you remove `gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(...);` in `setup()`, "verify" will work.

Comment: And I had to add  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); and now it works. PowerMock was not neccessary.